# Maven & Axis2 plugin - different stub code generation

Tags: maven, apache-axis, java

I'm using **Maven 3.0.4** and **Axis2 1.5.1** plugin. I've a problem with the generation of a stub class using AXIS2 plugin on Maven.

Depending on the JDK currently configured on the build environment, `AXIS2` plugin generates a different stub class source code. I've tried the generation using **JDK 1.6** and then **JDK 1.7**.

Is there any way to "force" the `JDK (i.e. 1.6)` used by the `AXIS2` plugin inside Maven (without changing environment)? (I would like to have a code generation independent from the environment)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How is maven-compiler-plugin configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, all my attempts are unsuccessful.

I have to resign myself to what I was shown in another post (http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-amp-Axis2-plugin-different-stub-code-generation-tc5730726.html ): if I really *require* this type of functionality, I may have to do this work yourself. Otherwise ask Axis2 devs if someone
will volunteer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you select your JDK like described here :

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html

Then, I would generate the stub using a different profile, allowing you to override some configuration, but keeping the benefits of your overall conf.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't solve the problem.